# Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher() in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on M2010J19SI in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

> Blockquote